# Why Count points in Polygon QGIS2.99 don't work properly?

Tags: qgis-3

I'm using QGIS 2.99 and try to count point in polygon with the function in vector analysis count points in polygon but don't have a correct result.

It must generate a polygon layer with the field count, but it is no generating all the polygons.

I use the same function in QGIS 2.18.16 and it works fine.

Here is the output from both.
[image]

Comment: please tell us some more about the layers

Comment: In qgis 2.99 it shows the following message... "El objeto (1351) tiene una geometría no válida. Por favor, corrija la geometría o cambie la configuración del Proceso a la opción "Ignorar objetos de entrada no válidos"... there are farms limits and the points are from a gps... we are trying to find if we visit all the farms. The message is shown when I try select by location too.